# How to create a custom controller for a content type in Drupal?

Tags: 9

I have a content type of node entity, when I follow /node/123 I want my custom controller to be applied. I created a route, but Drupal ignores it.

```
entity.node.my_route:
  path: '/node/{node}'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Collection'
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\PropertiesController::collection'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    no_cache: 'TRUE'
    parameters:
      collection:
        type: entity:node
```

In twig template I call it like:

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.my_route', {'node': node.id}) }}">
```

I also tried

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}">
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also it a little bit confuses me when I do following and visit /node/123/test:

```
entity.node.my_route:
  path: '/node/{node}/test'
  defaults:
```

My custom controller get loaded.

Comment: You can't just add another route for the same path, this doesn't override the core route. You have to alter the existing route, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215141/take-over-display-of-a-content-type-node-route

Comment: @4uk4 thanks! I think this is what I need. I suggest leaving this post open because I wasn't sure how to google this kind of problem and how it can be possibly named. 'How to custom controller for a content type' sounds legit to me.

Comment: @mevsme We still need to close it, just so new answers don't get posted here rather than on the canonical post. But its closed as a duplicate so it'll stay around in the SERPs for people who search for the problem with the same phrasing as you did